How to Constrain @Input Value to Specific Number Range in Angular
I'm trying to add an InputSignal to my Angular component, where the value must be an array of numbers. Each number should be between 0.01 and 10, and it cannot have more than 2 decimal places.
I want to enforce these constraints so that developers are informed if the provided value does not match the specified criteria. How can I type this InputSignal or add constraints to achieve this?
export class MyComponent {
public readonly value: InputSignal<valueType[]> = input<valueType[]>([]);
}


You could have an effect that throws when you're out-of-bound

@MatthieuRiegler What do you mean about 'effect'?

We can use the transform, to perform a simple validation, then use throw new Error(...) to show an error on the console!
import { Component, InputSignal, input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: ``,
})
export class Child {
  public readonly value: InputSignal<any[]> = input<any[], any[]>([], {
    transform: (data: any) => {
      const found = data.some((item: any) => item <= 10 && item >= 0.01);
      if (found) {
        throw new Error(
          'Array cannot contain values greater than 10 and less than 0.01'
        );
      }
      return data;
    },
  });
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child],
  template: `
    <app-child [value]="[1,2,3,4,100]"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I does not seem to work, No typescript error is showing when I set an invalid value

@Ryley38 We can only show javascript error on console, we cannot show typescript errors like this, typescript is mean't for type checking not value validation

So I didn't express myself well. I am actually looking to create a matching type so typescript will show an error. I could force user to set values with an enum, but it will be a huge enum.

@Ryley38 Sounds like a lot of work for a simple thing, try this option instead!

But it allows the developper to make a mistake. I am surprised typescript/angular has not something for this case

@Ryley38 that how it goes! anyway dev has to fix the error on the console, so they will catch it!
